# Двух или двоих?

Tags: грамотная-речь, количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

"Речь о двух пенсионерах" или "двоих пенсионерах"? Как правильно сказать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оба варианта допустимы, но, по-моему, стилистически правильнее "двух пенсионерах". "Двоих" - не требует пояснения, это собирательное.

Comment: Собирательное существительное-это что или кто,он или она?

Answer (score 9):

Два пенсионера или двое пенсионеров - не от стиля зависит, а от смысла. Собирательное числительное "двое" употребляем, если хотим подчеркнуть, что это группа, эти два пенсионера чем-то объединены, например вместе в домино играют. "Два пенсионера" тоже не возбраняется в таком случае. Но если я скажу, что у меня есть двое знакомых пенсионеров, а они никаким образом не связаны друг с другом, это будет ошибкой.

Comment: ППКС.......

Comment: ??????????????

Answer (score 4):

Варианты синонимичны, оба верны.
При синонимичности конструкций с количественными и собирательными числительными типа два друга – двое друзей возможен выбор одного из вариантов. 
Предпочтительно употребление собирательных числительных: 
1) с субстантивированными прилагательными мужского рода: двое прохожих, трое больных, четверо конвойных; 
2) с существительными мужского рода, имеющими в именительном падеже единственного числа окончание -а: двое мужчин, трое дедушек. 
В некоторых случаях, наоборот, не используются собирательные числительные, так как они вносят сниженный оттенок значения, например: два профессора, три генерала (не: «двое профессоров», «трое генералов»). 
Так что если Вы хотите проявить уважение к пенсионерам, предпочтительно сказать о двух пенсионерах,если для Вас это неважно, пожалуйста, говорите о двоих, но звучать это будет как разговорное(почти просторечное). Так что выбор за Вами.

Answer (score 0):

В формах косвенных падежей возможны оба варианта: двоих пенсионеров и двух пенсионеров т. к. это собирательное существительное

Comment: Пенсионер  -собирательное существительное???

Answer (score 0):

Если речь именно о количестве, то за это отвечает слово "двух". Если речь о составе (определенное количество как единое целое), то за это отвечает слово "двоих" (та самая парочка; тех самых двоих).