# Как пишется в родительном падеже: двух мальчиков или двоих мальчиков?

Tags: склонение, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

Как пишется в родительном падеже: двух мальчиков или двоих мальчиков?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Корректны оба варианта. Двоих - родительный падеж от собирательного числительного **двое**, а двух - от числительного **два**. Выбор зависит от контекста.

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200801009) об этом (и не только о мальчиках) хорошо и верно сказано. Процитирую:

> ...Итак, мужчин и юношей не может быть два, три, четыре. А вот мальчиков может быть и два (два мальчика – это как у героя «Служебного романа»: мальчик и мальчик), и двое.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь лучше ***двух мальчиков***.
[Двух или двоих?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11153) (Ларf, Людмила)

Вариант "двоих" возможен, но он будет означать, что это некая группа, а не просто два случайных мальчика.

Answer (score 0):

Употребление слова *двоих* возможно, но оно справедливо в отношении представителей мужского пола. Пока мальчики — ещё не мужчины и не парни, то могут разделять компанию девочек — исчисляться двумя, тремя и т. д.

Comment: Полная ерунда, shampar! Уж простите меня. Мальчики, по-Вашему, не мужского пола! А на самом деле мальчиков может быть как два, так и двое, хотя мужчин, действительно, только двое.

Comment: Мальчики — ещё не мужчины, утверждаю ещё раз.

Comment: Что не мужчины, это верно, но к представителям мужского пола они так или иначе относятся.

Comment: Не вижу противоречий.

Comment: Между чем и чем?

Comment: К представителям мужского пола они так или иначе относятся? — Я говорю: верно, я и не утверждал, что не относятся. Мальчики — ещё не мужчины, — говорю я.  Артём Луговой говорит: Что не мужчины, это верно. Противоречий не вижу.

Comment: А-а, перечитал и, кажется, понял Вас правильно. Тогда по-другому воспринял мысль. Так что простите! ;) Не понял тогда, что "употребление слова "двоих" ***/вообще/*** возможно". Даже уже затрудняюсь разобраться, **как** именно я тогда понял...)))

Comment: Да, я вспомнил, как понял тогда. *Пока мальчики... могут разделять компанию девочек...* — я подумал, что Вы имеете в виду, что ***только такой вариант возможен.*** И поэтому же они и не относятся к представителям мужского пола.

Answer (score 0):

Им. сколько?  два, три, четыре, пять (колич.числ)... двое, трое, четверо, пятеро (собир.числ) 
Род. (без) скольких? двух, двоих
Если речь именно о количестве, то за это отвечает слово "двух". Если речь о составе (определенное количество как единое целое), то за это отвечает слово "двоих" (та самая парочка; тех самых двоих).