# Употребление собирательных числительных

Tags: числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

> «За эту неделю исчезло трое мужиков, за прошлую двое».

Или:

> «За эту неделю исчезло три мужика, за прошлую два».

Помогите и объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: См также: [Двух или двоих?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11153/%d0%94%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%85)

Answer (score 1):

По моему главная ошибка обоих предложениий — это отсутствие тире перед последним числительным, которое должно в данном случае заменять пропущенное сказуемое

> За эту неделю исчезло трое мужиков, за прошлую — <sup>*(исчезло)*</sup> двое
>
> За эту неделю исчезло три мужика, за прошлую — <sup>*(исчезло)*</sup> два

в остальном оба предложения корректны, разве что стилистически форма числительных `двое, трое ... десятеро` больше уместна в сочетании с одушевлёнными существительными, как в приведённых примерах.

Answer (score 1):

**За эту неделю исчезло трое мужиков, за прошлую — двое.**

Здесь лучше использовать **собирательные числительные,** так как речь идет о совместном действии. Кроме того собирательное числительное может употреблять не только в числовом обороте, но и отдельно.

Во второй части желательное поставить **тире** на месте пропущенных слов в неполном предложении.

Comment: Спасибо! Я уж извелась. Написала «трое», «двое», а потом мучиться стала!

Answer (score 0):

Собирательные числительные "двое", "трое" следует употребить, если у нас, условно говоря, группа, то есть существует какая-то связь между мужиками. Кроме того, собирательные числительные придают речи оттенок разговорности, а в сводках о происшествиях, например, говорят о двух, трех и т.д. Слово *мужики* тоже несет оттенок разговорности, собирательные числительные сочетаются с ним хорошо, но все-таки решение зависит от контекста.

Тире во второй части желательно, но не обязательно.

Comment: Спасибо! Я уж извелась. Написала «трое», «двое», а потом мучиться стала! Тире не поставлю — оно предложение элегантностью подпортит.